# ListView and ListActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a program for Android do I need to modify my activity to be a ListActivity to use a ListView or can I just leave it as a regular activity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend your activity to make it a ListActivity.

Among the reasons is the fact that you get the onListItemClick() method which is called whenever you click a item which saves you from creating a listener.

Besides, you don't lose anything, if you want to change the layout of a ListActivity you still can with setContentView() method from Activity.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is NO.

You do not NEED to use ListActivity.

You can easily add a ListView to a regular Activity.

Comment: I don't think I can select both as answers but I'm going to give the credit to seth on this one for the extra explanation of why I might want to jump into ListActivity over just using a regular Activity. Thank you for the reply I do appreciate the straight up just answer =)